# .net Facebook redirect handler not working if not in root of site

Tags: facebook, redirect, facebook-c#-sdk

I have a Facebook canvas app developed in /net using C# and the latest Facebook SDK 5.xyz
Everything was working fine when i had the app was running a website where all files were on root directory ( http://localhost:81/ ).
Now I had to move (adapt) my app to run from a subdir of an existing website  ( http://localhost:81/MySiteFacebook/ )
in web.config i have

```
     <handlers>
  <add name="facebookredirect" path="facebookredirect.axd" verb="*" type="Facebook.Web.FacebookAppRedirectHttpHandler, Facebook.Web" />
```

But this way is not working, while the Authorization is doing the redirect i see in url:

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?scope=user_about_me,publish_stream,email&state=STATEHASHHER&client_id=CLIENTIDHERE&redirect_uri=http://localhost:81/facebookredirect.axd

if i manulay add in the url at redirect_uri the subdir and come with: http://localhost:81/MySiteFacebook/facebookredirect.axd

The redirect works fine, it sends me to my registration page.

Given this behavior i went back to my web.config and added the /MySiteFacebook/facebookredirect.axd to the 'path' of the handled.

Guess what? it is not adding this path to the redirect_uri.. ? :(

Any idea? please , Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're changing the web.config in the wrong place, you should be editing the urls in the facebookSettings such as:

```
<facebookSettings appId = "{app_id}" appSecret = "{app_secret}"
     canvasPage = "http://apps.facebook.com/{canvas_page}/"
     canvasUrl = "http://localhost:81/MySiteFacebook"
     secureCanvasUrl = "https://localhost:81/MySiteFacebook" />
```

Comment: the handler is defined outside the facebookSettings section.

Comment: The handler is defined outside the facebookSettings section but the URLs used by the website are defined within the facebookSettings  section. It then follows the redirect path passed to FB is defined within the facebookSettings section. The facebookredirect.axd handler location is relative to the root of your canvas app(defined in facebookSettings .) Did you try actually changing it in here?